# problem using cat in windows

Tags: makefile, cat

I'm using the windowsxp. The version of 'cat' that I'm using comes bundled with the [arduino](http://arduino.cc) download.

The makefile runs cat.

Here is the output:

```
cat \arduino-0012\hardware\cores\arduino\main.cxx >> applet\foo.cpp
cat: arduino-0012hardwarecoresarduinomain.cxx: No such file or directory
make: *** [applet_files] Error 1
```

I also tried the forward slash, /, but that gives

```
cat: /arduino-0012/hardware/cores/arduino/main.cxx: No such file or directory
```

(doubling up the back slashes, \, didn't help)

However, if I run the cat command manually, it works. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use a normal looking file path?

Comment: "problem using cat in windows" - what would a non-programmer think? :)

Comment: d03boy: like g:\arduino-0012\.... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the tools, but it looks like you might need to escape (double up) the backslashes in the makefile, as the error message shows the path without any backslashes.

Alternatively, it may be expecting a Unix-style path which would have forward slashes instead.

**New info**:  It looks like there were two changes needed:  (a) use forward slashes, and (b) specify the drive, because Unix-like environments don't default that as DOS would.

Answer (score 1):

By the error i'll be guessing that the cat expects you to give the other slash to it.

'/' instead of '\'

Not sure though try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Unix style paths worked, but not a relative path. I had to use g:/....